# hierarchical json data from flat json

Tags: javascript, json

I have parent-child JSON data and I want to get all children (nested children) from a selected parent in the specific year-wise data format as below

```
var data = [{ "Id": "1", "Name": "abc", "EnteredOn": "03/01/2019", "attr": "abc" },
           { "Id": "2", "Name": "abcd", "EnteredOn": "02/01/2018", "attr": "abc" },
           { "Id": "3", "Name": "abcde", "EnteredOn": "04/01/2019", "attr": "abc" },
           { "Id": "4", "Name": "abcdef", "EnteredOn": "01/01/2016", "attr": "abc" }];
```

output:

```
{
  "year": "2019",
  "children": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "Name": "abc",
      "Date": "03/01/2019"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: I have tried to get the required out with d3.nest and linq.js and able to get it.https://jsfiddle.net/zarekars/z2sj4nth/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, i recommend adding `year` attribute

```
data.forEach(a=> a['year'] = a.EnteredOn.getFullYear()
```

and using Lodash `_.groupBy` function

```
 data.groupBy("year")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable solution. I am able to get the output with the available year with the help of d3.nest and linq.js with their child nodes but in case if I don't have specific year data like [2012,2011] in JSON in that case how to display the parent year like Year: 2012, Children {[]} in such a format.

Comment: I have created this JSFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/zarekars/z2sj4nth/1/

Comment: what didn't work with my solution?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your solution and it's absolutely working fine but need an output in a different way which I have mentioned in the fiddle. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Koder Great! so you can mark the answer